# Custom Toast in one line

Tags: android

I've used a custom toast to by an ImageView and TextView.
[This is how Toast be shown in this activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N35iF.png)

But as shown, it does have enough space to let the Toast show in 1 line, but it didn't. If it is just a regular TextView, it would also show in 1 line. Are there anyone can tell me how to solve this.
Here is my Java Code:

```
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(ETtoast.getText().length()>15){
                ETtoast.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(
                        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                showToast();
            }
        }

        private void showToast() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_root));
            Toast toast= new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }
```

[Here is xml layout of this Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLC3Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your custom **toast** xml layout within the **text view** attributes add the following attribute:-

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Per the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) this should force your **text view** to occupy a single line.